# Фрактальный генератор случайных чисел

Tags: javascript, графика, шифрование

Необходимо создать функцию фрактального генератора случайных чисел на JavaScript. Данная функция необходима для создания ключа, который используется при шифровании растрового изображения. Ключ генерируется, но только стандартными методами, а вот как сделать фрактальный генератор - ума не приложу. Буду очень благодарна за ответ.

Comment: А где вопрос?

Comment: Хех, а другая копия сего поста имеет предикат "Срочно!"

Comment: Вам необходимо приобрести следующую публикацию: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5671262&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D5671262

Answer (score -1):

```
function randMinMax (max, min){
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1 - min)); /* Including max */
}
```

Comment: 1. Ну да, `Math.random` - это прям для криптографии. 2. А фрактальность тут при чём?